# Unrecognized selector error in SWIFT

Tags: swift, function, class, selector, nstimer

I have a custom class "MyTask" that gets called from other classes like class "ViewController". Inside "MyTask" I have function "startTask" that takes parameters required to start NSTimer to execute function "doStuff"
However when I use function startTask and set the selector for other function it crashes

```
 class MyTask {
            var timer = NSTimer()
            var timerInterval = 0.0
            var target: AnyObject!
            var selector = Selector()

            func startTask(time: Double, target target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) {
                self.timerInterval = time
                self.target = target
                self.selector = selector
                doStuff()
            }
func doStuff() {
//....some code here to run
//====Crash happens on this line=====
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.timerInterval, target: self, selector: self.selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

In my other class here is what I do

```
class ViewController {
   let mynewClass = MyTask()
   mynewClass = startTask(2, target: self, selector_: #selector(updateLabel))

func updateLabel() { print("") }
}
```

I am getting an error *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fe90242f6f0 of class 'abc' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[.abc timerAction]

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You should name all your classes starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: In addition to what @LeoDabus said, you should also not append "_" to your parameter names. Instead, use the normal parameter name. Then in the implementation of the initializer or method, use `self.` to set properties with the same name as a parameter, like this: `self.target = target`

Comment: Leo, abc is just an example..

Answer (score 1):

The class that is to be the target of the selector *must* derive from NSObject. You're using an Objective-C feature here; you have to have an Objective-C-compatible class.